# Scalling flask socket io with redis connecting to only one server port

Tags: nginx, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy, flask-socketio

I have real time chatapplication, unable to scale them.

so i have frontend ngnix which proxy pass to backend ngnix , now backend ngnix will upstream to flasksocket io multiple instance,

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
#server_name xx.xxx.xx.xxx;
client_max_body_size 300M;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/newssl/ssl_bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/newssl/example.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers 'xxx+xxxx+xxxx';
set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
real_ip_recursive on;
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" ;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

location / {
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_read_timeout 120s;
                    proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
                    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
                    open_file_cache_valid 65s;
                    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
                    open_file_cache_errors on;
                    proxy_buffering    on;
                    proxy_buffer_size  128k;
                    proxy_buffers 100  128k;
                    client_max_body_size 0M;
                    proxy_pass http://live_chatnodes;
```

> backend ngnix

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name 10.0.2.9;
            client_max_body_size 300M;
            location / {
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_read_timeout 120s;
                    proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
                    open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
                    open_file_cache_valid 65s;
                    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
                    open_file_cache_errors on;
                    proxy_buffering    on;
                    proxy_buffer_size  128k;
                    proxy_buffers 100  128k;
                    client_max_body_size 0M;
                    proxy_pass http://live_nodes;
                    }
```

> this now pass request to upstream and upstream has 15 nodes, how ever all the request are going to one flasksocket io. which is causing my system go down. and last info upstream has iphash as per flaskcoketio documentation.
> all my clients are using vpn so they have static ip as well,

Comment: Do you have a good variety of IP ddressses? The ip_hash algorithm creates a hash of the client's IP address and then selects a server based on the result. If, for example, you have all your clients coming from the same IP address, then it is expected that they will all go to the same server.

Comment: But that is creating a load on one server, actually all my clients are comming from whatsapp and it lands on middleware from where it connect to livechat, now my middleware will definitely have one ip , and all my request are going to one server. which cause entire production down. How to hande such situation

Comment: @MiguelGrinberg Still waiting

Comment: I'm not sure how I can help with this. Your issue is that you have a single client making many connections. The ip_hash load balancing in nginx is working as designed by keeping every client going to the same server. You have only one client, so nginx is working correctly. Unless you find a way to preserve your clients I don't see how you can make load balancing work, but maybe there is some way I don't know about, I really have no experience with a set up like yours. Sorry.